# Does a natural transformation of functors induce a natural transformation between their right adjoints?

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors

Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be two categories and $F$ and $G: \mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$ be two functors. Suppose $F$ and $G$  have right adjoints $F^{\wedge}$ and $G^{\wedge}: \mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{C}$.

Now let $T:F\Rightarrow G$ be a natural transformation.

> > My question is: does $T$ induce a natural transformation $T^{\wedge}:G^{\wedge}\Rightarrow F^{\wedge}$?

Comment: Yes. Let $\eta: 1 \to F^\wedge F$ denote the unit and $\varepsilon: G G^\wedge \to 1$ the counit. Then form the evident composite $$G^\wedge \stackrel{\eta G^\wedge}{\to} F^\wedge F G^\wedge \stackrel{F^\wedge TG^\wedge}{\to} F^\wedge G G^\wedge \stackrel{F^\wedge \varepsilon}{\to} F^\wedge$$

Comment: The evident composite in Todd's comment  obviously agrees with the transformation you would get by using the adjunction : $F\to G$ gives $id \to F^\wedge G$ which gives $G^\wedge \to F^\wedge$, as precomposition by $G$ becomes right adjoint to precomposition by $G^\wedge$ (although of course the easiest way to prove this is with the unit and co-unit, so in the end we really get down to Todd's comment)

Comment: I seem to recall that the natural transformation between the adjoints is called its **mate**.

Comment: What Paul says is correct, and it resonates most convincingly when you hear an Australian category theorist say it. (I tend to be somewhat lax [haha] in my usage, where any morphism you derive from an adjunction in similar fashion could also be called a "mate". For example, in informal chat, I might also refer to Maxime's $id \to F^\wedge G$ as a mate.)

Comment: Some non-Australians refer to such a transformation as a "conjugate".  The general definition of [mate](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/mate) involves a square of four functors, two with adjoints, and taking a couple to be identities in different ways we obtain both your $G^\wedge \Rightarrow F^\wedge$, Todd's $\mathrm{Id} \to F^\wedge G$, and others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I should have made my comment an answer earlier. The answer is yes:

Let $\eta: 1 \to F^\wedge F$ denote the unit of the adjunction and $\varepsilon: G G^\wedge \to 1$ the counit. Then form the composite

$$G^\wedge \stackrel{\eta G^\wedge}{\to} F^\wedge F G^\wedge \stackrel{F^\wedge TG^\wedge}{\to} F^\wedge G G^\wedge \stackrel{F^\wedge \varepsilon}{\to} F^\wedge.$$